# Domain time issue, server to clients

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012, time

I have a server 2012 running as the DC also running DHCP.  I have three PCs on this domain right now and all three get the incorrect time.

The server has the proper time set and the proper time zone and displays it correctly in the lower right of the taskbar.  However even after I manually correct the time on the clients they immediately go back two hours.  the time zone on the clients are set correctly, daylight savings time I do have checked for all the clients and the server because naturally I do want it to do that.

I can't figure this one out.  I have even tried adding a time and NTP server as my server and even tried one of the government NTP servers as well.  Adding these to my DHCP scope of course.  None of these tries helped correct the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use DHCP to configure time sources for Active Directory domain members.

Member servers and workstations should be synchronizing time from a domain controller, not an external time source:

**Configure a client computer for automatic domain time synchronization**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8990703a-a197-4717-b6e5-b7406d9f91f0

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update 
net stop w32time & net start w32time
```

That configuration can be specified in Group Policy.

To display the status of the time service:

```
w32tm /query /status /verbose
```

Your DC also needs to be advertising as a time server.  To display the time server advertising status on your DC:

```
C:\ nltest /server:win2008r2addc1 /dsgetdc:contoso.com

           DC: \\WIN2008R2ADDC1.contoso.com
      Address: \\192.168.135.133
     Dom Guid: 0db7aee9-a93c-4f26-bed6-ee9894886573
     Dom Name: contoso.com
  Forest Name: contoso.com
 Dc Site Name: Default-First-Site-Name
Our Site Name: Default-First-Site-Name
        Flags: PDC GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV GTIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE FULL_SECRET WS
```

Note the TIMESERV flag, that indicates your DC is advertising as a time server.  If it is the forest root PDC Emulator role, it will also have the GTIMESERV flag.  The forest root PDC Emulator is the only computer that should synchronize with an external time source.

An example of how to configure the forest root PDC emulator with the NIST NTP source:

```
 w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time.nist.gov /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
```

**Configure the Windows Time service on the PDC emulator in the Forest Root Domain**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce8890cf-ef46-4931-8e4a-2fc5b4ddb047

**Windows Time Service Group Policy Settings**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#w2k3tr_times_tools_vwtt

Answer (score 1):

- Clean all that junk out of your DHCP options.
- Clean out any Windows Time configuration settings that you made on the PCs. To reset the time service to factory defaults:

  - `net stop w32time`
  - `w32tm /unregister`
  - `w32tm /register`
  - `net start w32time`
- If any of the machines are virtual machines, then either make sure that the time synchronization is turned off in the guest VM integration services, or ensure that the time is correct on the hypervisor.

Alright, let's begin...

**On Your Domain Controller**

Your forest root PDCE needs to be synchronizing with an external time source:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"0.us.pool.ntp.org" /reliable:yes /update
```

Watch the logs on the DC and ensure that this results in valid time data being received from the NTP server.

`w32tm /query /peers` will confirm what NTP servers you are receiving time data from.

All other DCs should be set to the NT5DS time sync setting. There should be only *one* single machine in your entire forest that is synchronizing with an external time service, and that is your forest root PDCE.

**On Your PC**

All you need to do is unregister and re-register w32time as I've shown above.  The default behavior is for the client PCs to be using the "NT5DS" or "Domhier" setting, which is what you what you want. That means they instinctively know to get time sync data from their domain controllers. You can use `w32tm /query /configuration` to verify that they are in NT5DS mode and not NTP mode.

If everything else is working as it should, then this is all there is to it. If you have any other problems, then you will have to provide a lot more detail.  We'll need log events and all of this w32tm output from you.

Comment: @gregaskew Thank you both for your answers and the bit of schooling I just got :)  This setup is my own stuff at home for learning so it is not anything immediately important.  As soon as I get a chance I will try your answers and report back to highlight the answer.